# I want to write a function that takes a list and returns it with all duplicates removed, without creating another list or string

Tags: python

I have tried this, it gives the output it should give([1,3,2]), however the problem is it keeps printing the output for infinite times without stop,, is there any solutions with out changing the idea of the code.

```
a= [1,2,2,2,1,3,2]
def rem_dup(L):
    while len(L):
        for i in L:
            y= L.count(i)
            if y>1:
                L.remove(i)  
        print L 
rem_dup(a)
```

Comment: Why can't you create another list? Your algorithm is O(n^2) which means it will be very inefficient for large lists

Comment: `list(set(a))` is the simplest, although it does require intermediate data structures. This smells like homework to me.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, assuming the items in `a` are hashable ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the point of this function is to exercise your python skills, it sounds like you want a `set`. A set is like a list but does not allow duplicate values. If you want your final data structure to be a list, you could do something like this:

```
final_list = list(set(original_list))
```

Comment: There are probably valid use-cases for wanting to remove duplicates from a list in-place.

Answer (score 2):

One way to safely do this is to loop over the list in reverse and remove only from the back:

```
>>> for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
...    if a.count(a[i]) > 1:
...       del a[i]
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

But this will be polynomial time, since `a.count` is linear and so is `del a[i]`.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy yes, yes, to be precise it is quadratic time.

Answer (score 1):

`while len(L)` will always be true as long as `L` had something in it to begin with

Modifying L while using it with the `for` loop can cause items to be skipped, so you have a bug for some inputs.

If you fix that problem, you shouldn't need the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the items in `a` are hashable and you don't mind that the remaining items aren't in the same order when you started, you can create an intermediate `set` and replace the original contents in-place.

```
a[:] = set(a)
```